# Complex query - not sure if possible?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have sat for quite some time trying to work this out and just can't manage it!
So here goes....

I have a player table

id | careerid | teamid

The teamid is linked to the id of the following team id

id | userid | careerid

Each user on my site has a session variable called id.

They are bidding on the player and when doing so, I need to use a query to check if the careerid of the player matches the careerid of the team table and then in the team table if the users session variable is present in the userid field.

Help please!!!

Comment: I don't really understand the structure of your tables, and the output you need to obtain. Can you clarify your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're passing the "users session variable" into the query as the @userId parameter, wouldn't something like this work?

```
SELECT player.id
FROM player
INNER JOIN team ON player.teamid = team.id AND player.careerid = team.careerid
WHERE team.userid = @userId
```

If that query returns a result, the player(s) returned are associated with the team specified by `@userId`, and have the same `careerId` as the team.

Comment: I wasnt aware you can join two none-PK fields and have an AND on a join! Cheers